# Sleeping a spawned thread

Tags: c++, lambda, sleep

I want to spawn a thread that loops and constantly checks if keys are being pressed. I tried:

```
void EventHandler::listenForPresses(int loopMSDelay) {
    listenOnKeys = true;
    listeningThread = std::thread ([&]{
        do {

            std::cout << "Looped!\n";
            updatePressedKeys();
            actOnPressedKeys();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(loopMSDelay));

        } while (listenOnKeys);
    });
}
```

The problem is, the `sleep_for` has very odd behavior in this case; it seems to permanently suspend the spawned thread instead of sleeping for `loopMSDelay` milliseconds.

Without the `std::this_thread::sleep_for...` line (with it commented out), it runs fine (although it loops much faster than I want).

With the above line though, it displays the "Looped!" message once, then never again (by "never", I waited a couple minutes, and nothing). This suggests that it's freezing on the sleep line for some reason.

The only thing I can think of is it's getting "confused" because I'm calling the `sleep_for` in a lambda in the main thread (in the `this_thread` namespace), but expecting it to sleep the spawned thread.

Whats the best way around this? I've read that `this_thread::sleep_for` is the preferred way to sleep (when sleeping is appropriate), so I've always used it since picking up C++ again.

Comment: "This suggests that it's freezing on the sleep line for some reason." Have you actually verified this in a debugger?

Comment: maybe you gave wrong parameter in `loopMSDelay`? did you try fixed value in the `sleep_for`? like: `std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));`

Comment: @MrEricSir Not using a "legit" debugger, but I surrounded it in print statements, and the one before it prints, but never the one immediately after it.

Comment: @SHR Yes, I've verified that it's not a weird time being passed it. The default is 100 milliseconds, and I'm not calling it with arguments, so it should check (theoretically), 10 times a second.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Anyway if its not working for a variable, I would check if a fixed constant is working. if it does, there is something wrong with your code, (maybe a wrong argument?), if it doesn't, it can be some compiler bag etc. anyway it is an easy test...

Comment: @SHR  Already tried using a constant as well. And I'm using VS, so unless it's a quirk of it, that's unlikely. Plus, `sleep_for` works fine on the main thread (I've used it many times), it's just having problems in the spawned thread.

Comment: @T.C. Ya, in retrospect, that's unnecessary. You think that could cause it though? I went for a walk, so I'll try that when I get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda captures by reference `loopMSDelay`, which is a function argument whose lifetime ends at the end of the function call.

Which means that your thread will hold a dangling reference, and has undefined behavior when it attempts to use it. In practice, it likely passed some random large number (which resided at where `loopMSDelay` used to be) to `sleep_for`, which explains what you observe.

Use `[=]` to capture by value.

Comment: That's actually pretty funny, but makes perfect sense. I'll try it in a few minutes.

Comment: I thought I substituted in a constant. Sorry @SHR, your suggestion would have solved it too. And yes, changing it to capture by value fixed it. Thank you.